# Using a created variable to call on another variable with action, HOWLER js

Tags: jquery

On the page I've already defined:

```
var sound_thunderstorm = new Howl({  src: ['thunderstorm.mp3'], preload: true });
```

I can play this sound by doing: **sound_thunderstorm.play();** -- works great!
This is a global var, so I can call it anywhere.

---

Then after a mouse click, I want it to play the sound that is in the data-soundclick attribute:

```
var soundfile = 'sound_'+jQuery(this).data('soundclick');
```

^
This means that soundfile now = 'sound_thunderstorm'
However... **soundfile.play()**, won't work... as it is not recognizing 'sound_thunderstorm'....

How can I use a variable to call on another variable? Is that the right term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved if anyone ever needs:

var soundfile = **window[**'sound_'+jQuery(this).data('soundclick')**]**;

allows:
soundfile.play() to work and play

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).